# Laravel Artisan - Cli doesnt reads environment variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I had made a custom artisan command. In homestead everything goes right, but when I execute the command on server it cant read environment variables. When I ssh the server and try `php artisan external:import` the connection timeouts cause of null env vars.

On artisan tinker env() function returns null.

How can I read env vars on server?

IMPORTANT: This server is part of AWS, so it does not have `.env` file.

Comment: AWS servers can have .env files, why is this a problem on your server?

Comment: IT dept configure in this way. I cant deploy .env files.

Comment: You can't you will have to set those variables in config files or where ever you call env()

Comment: Understood. Laravel takes the default settings from the config folder files, if no .env is in place. Do you have every needed setting in there? Not sure if your custom artisan command needs a DB for example.

Comment: The envs are configured in server directly, in configuration files I have the env() function and I can get the vars on web. But not in command line

Comment: What was your server setup on AWS? Are you still having a problem with this or did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: I am not in that project anymore, so I dont know the AWS configuration. But I had to change almost everything 'cause I dont get it working.

Answer (score 1):

did you clear config cache already?

```
php artisan config:clear
```

i think env function did not work after you cached the config

Comment: Yes, I did the condfig cache clear. Even with launching all the commands at the same time: `source /etc/environment-vars && sudo php artisan config:cache && sudo php artisan external:import`, it fails

Comment: ```php artisan config:clear``` , ```php artisan cache:clear``` , ```php artisan view:clear``` ,```php artisan route:clear``` , ```composer dump-autoload```  , could u please run all these commands and  tell the results? and please do not cache config for this test

Comment: I did. Same result. Cannot access environtment variables on CLI.

Comment: check what happens to bootstrap/cache/config.php file after running commands

Comment: @MohamadKarimi he has no .env file, still it should work using the config files.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late to answer this question, however, I'll share my experience in case it can help someone.

The environment variables will be available depending on how they have been configured. The different ways to configure these variables are:

1. Setting them for the current user ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile
2. Setting them globally with the /etc/profile file or with a file in the /etc/profile.d/ directory
3. Establishing them at the web server software level. For example, in the httpd.conf file with SetEnv, in apache.

If you have set environment variables through server software, they will be available only to scripts that handle http requests. This leaves out the artisan commands.

My recommendation is that you add a step to your deployment process to set environment variables globally by creating a new file in /etc/profile.d/. For example, /etc/profile.d/webapp.sh. So webapp.sh would have lines like

```
MY_VAR=my-value
```

I hope this helps you.